# how to add source control to sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, tfs

I'm newbie to TFS it, and i have installed it already. Everything works fine but strangely i find no source control on SQL server management studio 2008 r2 (tools/options) as in the below image

[image]

What should i do now ?

Thanks,
Nam Vo

Answer (score 4):

You need [Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bce06506-be38-47a1-9f29-d3937d3d88d6). And then you can add SSMS projects to source control (just like in Visual Studio).

From my experience- working with SSMS and TFS is not very comfortable. Third party tools could be much nicer choice (for example red-gate, although havent really worked with their source control tools).

Answer (score 1):

The SSMS plug-in from Red Gate will easily connect SQL Server to TFS (and all other version control systems) - check it out at http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/

(Disclaimer - in the interests of being up-front, I work for Red Gate)